# COUNTIFing within rows I'm already COUNTIFing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif

**I have a table that looks like the "table" below.** Each category, of which there are three in this case, can have multiple items. *Item names are never duplicated.* Each item has its own status.

```
Category | Item  | Status    
DMS123   | LKJ-9 | DONE    
DMS123   | LMS-5 | IN PROGRESS    
DMS123   | RGH-4 | IN PROGRESS    
DMS123   | RML-4 | IN PROGRESS    
LDP456   | TWD-2 | DONE    
LDP456   | RGA-5 | DONE    
LDP456   | PLY-6 | IN PROGRESS    
KFT789   | TIJ-1 | IN PROGRESS    
KFT789   | CML-1 | IN PROGRESS    
KFT789   | PRS-6 | IN PROGRESS
```

**The result I'm looking for is the following:**

```
Category | # of items DONE | # of items IN PROGRESS    
DMS123   | 1               | 3    
LDP456   | 2               | 1    
KFT789   | 0               | 3
```

**I believe I should be using a COUNTIF statement**, but I need to do a COUNTIF within a COUNTIF. All I've found online so far is how to do two COUNTIF statements, but that just searches the entire selected column twice; it does not search within a search, if that makes sense. Note also that all this data is contained in Excel tables and the categories can change dynamically and there are hundreds of them. If at all possible, **I would prefer not selecting each category column individually and then doing one COUNTIF on it to count the item statuses.**

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a pivot table. Or use COUNTIFS.

Comment: I would definitely use a pivot table for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### COUNTIFS vs PivotTable

**COUNTIFS**

A pretty lame solution, since as you get more items you have to manually add them in the orange table (Note: BBB333 isn't there.). The formula in F2 is:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$C:$C,RIGHT(F$1,LEN(F$1)-LEN("# of items ")))
```

Copy and apply paste formulas to G2. The rest will be done automatically when adding new data into Category.

[image]

**PivotTable in Excel 2019**

Go to Insert>PivotTable and choose a table (Blue Table (Table1)) and a location (E8) and choose OK.

[image]

Now you tick Category and Status, and drag and drop Status to Columns and then again Status, this time to Values and play around with the settings. Still it is not perfect because you'll have to refresh the table as you add new data (right-click Refresh). You could "fix" this with a VBA event.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My table of data is actually much, much bigger than what I provided here, so your first option actually worked better than the pivot table. The extra manual work in the future won't be too bad. Thanks for your quick response!